# In install4j, how does executeScheduleUpdate work?

Tags: install4j

If I have multiple applications installed with install4j and scheduling updates, how does UpdateChecker.isUpdateScheduled and UpdateChecker.executeScheduleUpdate know with application I am meaning to update?

None of them receive application ids nor paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes in the API, such as `UpdateChecker` are loaded from the JAR file `.install4j/i4jruntime.jar`. This identifies the installation directory.

You cannot use the API to update other installed applications, you would have to call the updater executables of those installations.

Comment: how exactly do I call the updater or other applications? Originally I tried calling the exe/script of the updater directly and was working on Windows, but I read on another question that a mac single bundle doesn't have such an executable.

Now I have switched to calling ApplicationLauncher.launchApplication, but I am getting java.io.IOException: Application with ID 293 could not be found.

This application's launcher is on a parent directory than the one using the api.

Comment: `ApplicationLauncher.launchApplication` cannot be used for other installations. For single bundle macOS there is indeed no executable to call.

Comment: Ingo, I am stuck here, given your response, I can't resolve [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59075863/how-to-lunch-update-for-different-application).  Any thoughts?

Comment: You could call an updater application with ID 293 for a different installation with a java executable like this: `java  -cp i4jruntime.jar;user.jar;user\* com.install4j.runtime.installer.Application 293`, that would work for a single bundle archive as well.